# SharedPreference - how to?

Tags: android, android-intent, sharedpreferences

I have created launcher activity wherein the user will give the details such as first name, last name, contact and email. On clicking the button I want it to store in the shared preference file and then move to next activity. But this is not happening in this case. Another activity is not even started. Whereas if I write the code for writing in shared preference file and just keep the intent stuff in the `onclick` function ie test in my case then it is starting another activity. Why is this happening?

```
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText e1,e2,e3,e4;
    SharedPreferences sp;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        sp=getSharedPreferences("myuser", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        EditText e1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.t1);
        EditText e2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.t2);
        EditText e3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.t3);
        EditText e4=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.t4);
        if(sp.contains("fname"))
        {
            e1.setText(sp.getString("fname",""));
        }
        if(sp.contains("lname"))
        {
            e2.setText(sp.getString("lname",""));
        }
        if(sp.contains("email"))
        {
            e3.setText(sp.getString("email",""));
        }

        if(sp.contains("contact"))
        {
            e4.setText(sp.getString("contact",""));
        }

    }
    public void test(View v)
    {   String f=e1.getText().toString();
        String l=e2.getText().toString();
        String em=e3.getText().toString();
        String c=e4.getText().toString();
        SharedPreferences.Editor ed=sp.edit();
        ed.putString("fname",f);
        ed.putString("lname",l);
        ed.putString("email",em);
        ed.putString("contact",c);
        ed.commit();
        Intent i=new Intent(this,Act2.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the Exception you're getting? Where's the sp variable coming from? Are you sure the test function gets called on the button click?

Comment: You're not setting onclick listener for the button.

Comment: @Sander I have updated the  code.

Comment: Above is the full code for launcher.

Answer (score 0):

Set onClickListener(), Should like something like.

```
Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override public void onClick(View view) {
    test(view);
  }
});
```

Comment: But if  I put the code for writing in shared preference file in the onCreate function then the button is moving to another activity

Comment: If you add the snippet of the code I've attached inside onCreate(), the new activity will start after you click the button.

Comment: Make sure the button has correct Id, the one you have defined in your xml layout file.

Comment: I've updated the code. Just copy and paste then change the button id.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have create two objects of each edit text..one is inside onCreate and another is outside onCreate.

You are getting values from outside edit text which are not casted and you are using setText in another editText....

Please check the objects which should be only one.